# R For loop replace previsouly assigned values

Tags: r, for-loop

I'd like to use uniform distribution to randomly assign value 1 or 2 for five groups(generate 5 random uniform distribution), with each group containing 10 samples.

I try to write:

```
for(i in 1:5){
        rf <- runif(10)
      result[rf<=0.5]=1
      result[rf>0.5]=2
      }
```

However this will replace the previously assigned values when the loop goes on.
The code produces only 10 results:

```
1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1
```

But I want a total of 50 randomized values:

```
1 2 1 2 ...... 2 1 1
```

How to do this? Thank you

Comment: based on your description, i'm not sure if you want `(runif(50) > 0.5) + 1` or `replicate(5, (runif(10) > 0.5) + 1)`

Comment: If you have a for loop over `i` and you don't use `i` inside the for loop, that's usually an indicator that something is wrong.

Comment: I'd also point out that you can sample from 1 and 2 directly rather than relying on a `runif` and a cutoff - `sample(1:2, size = 50, replace = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Since, you are working on random number generated from same distribution every time, you can better generate 50 numbers in once, and assign value using `ifelse` function.

Try this:

```
a <- ifelse(runif(50) <= 0.5, 1, 2)
dim(a) <- c(10,5) #if result in matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Gregor Thomas' advice, `sample...`  You can also covert the stream into a matrix of 5 columns (groups) of 10.

```
nums <- sample(1:2, 50, replace = TRUE)
groups <- matrix(nums, ncol = 5)
```